# Multiple http response poco.

Tags: sql-server, http, client, httpresponse, poco

Hi, I want to send one HTTP request and received multiple responses, but I don't know how to do it. I use standard functions for it.

I have like this:

```
        HTTPSClientSession session("localhost", 9090);
    session.setKeepAlive(true);

    HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/",    HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
    session.sendRequest(req);

    // get response
    HTTPResponse res;
    cout << res.getStatus() << " " << res.getReason() << endl;

    // print response
    istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
    StreamCopier::copyStream(is, cout);
    cout << "" << endl;

    //get annother response
    HTTPResponse res2;
    istream &is2 = session.receiveResponse(res2);
    StreamCopier::copyStream(is2, cout);
    cout << "" << endl;
```

And server part as following:

```
virtual void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest &request, HTTPServerResponse &response) {  
            response.setStatus(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");


        ostream& out = response.send();
        out << "WAIT FOR RESULT" <<endl;
        out.flush();


        response.setStatus(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.send();
        ostream &o = response.send();
        o << "RESULT" << endl;
        o.flush();
}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTTP doesn't support this kind of functionality, maybe you should create your own protocol within HTTP, say you want to have two answers, return a body in the response that is formated to support multiple answers,
EG:

```
[
  {
    response{status:200, accept:application/json, body:{...}}
  },
  {
    response{status:404, accept:application/json, body:{...}}
  }
]
```

What you are looking for is a websocket as far as I'm concerned, you should study the WS protocol for establishing one and being able to send and receive information live, or you could use another technology like [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) that makes this super easy.

More about websockets on [treehouse team's blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets)